# Converting column of decimals to currency in web grid

Tags: c#, view, asp.net-mvc-5, webgrid

How can I convert the Freight column, which contains decimal values, to show in currency?

I have tried:

```
grid.Column(header: "Freight", columnName: "Freight", style: "Freight", format: item => item.ToString("C")),
```

But I get an error:  **No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguments**

Note: This column is a Nullable column from a table from a database

Comment: Try `item.Value.ToString("C")`, since its a Nullable column, you must first retrieve it's value before converting to string. This error exists because you will throw a runtime exception if the value of item is ever Null.

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you tried casting it to a decimal (if not null), like so: ((decimal)item).ToString("C")?

Comment: Just tried that and now I'm getting: Cannot convert type 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGridRow' to 'decimal'

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

grid.Column(header: "Freight", columnName: "Freight", style: "Freight", format: item => item.**Freight**.ToString("C")),